# Multiple Route registration in Asp.net MVC Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area by the name `Admin`, and in `AdminAreaRegistration` i define route like blow:

```
   public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {Controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
         name: "Product",
          url: "Admin/ProductForm-{FormName}",
         defaults: new { controller = "ProductForm", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
    }
}
```

and in `ProductFormController` (in `Admin` area) i have :

```
 public ActionResult Index(string FormName)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

when i want to go to this url:`http://localhost:5858/Admin/ProductForm-mobile`, it should route to `Index` action in the `ProductFormController`(with FormName=mobile), but it didn't. what is the problem?

Comment: Where it redirects to?

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak it give me `404` eror

Comment: Put `Admin_defaut` route last. The default route should be always the last one.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak thank you my friend, it works, plz add ur comment as answer then i mark it as correct answer, it may be other people question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC the route mechanism works in a very simple way, at the first match will redirect to that pattern, ignoring the upcoming ones. That's why the Default Route should always be the last.

You need to move your `"Admin_defaut"` route to the end.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {Controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    context.MapRoute(
     name: "Product",
      url: "Admin/ProductForm-{FormName}",
     defaults: new { controller = "ProductForm", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Correct implementation:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Product",
        url: "Admin/ProductForm-{FormName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "ProductForm", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {Controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```